# All pairs sum to a different value

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

If we consider the integers $\{1,\dots,n\}$, what is the size of the largest subset $A$ so that all  distinct pairs $x, y \in A$ sum to a different value?  For this to make sense $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ are considered to be the same pair.

For $n=10$ you can get $A=\{1,2,3,5,8\}$. For $n=20$ you can get $A=\{1,2,3,5,8,13\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a property of Fibonacci numbers, and thus
$$
|A|\approx \frac{\log n}{\log\varphi},
$$
where
$$
\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$
This can be done inductively in the following way: If every integer $m\le f_k$
can be written as a sum of at most one pair in $\{f_1,\ldots,f_k\}$, then every
integer $m'\le f_{k+1}$
can be written as a sum of at most one pair in $\{f_1,\ldots,f_k,f_{k+1}\}$.

Comment: Can this be proven maximal?

Comment: @user117230: $1+12=5+8$

Comment: Yes.  Hopefully fixed that.

Comment: Take $n=50$. Doesn't $1, 5, 12, 25, 27, 35, 41, 44$ work?

Comment: @felix: Your choice of numbers works, but $1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34$ are also eight, and their largest is $34$, instead of $44$.

Comment: OK how about $5, 7, 17, 52, 56, 67, 80, 81, 100, 122, 138, 159, 165, 168, 191, 199$? I think your method would give $|A|  = 11$.

Comment: @felix: Good example - any general rule?

Comment: It seems just to be this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_ruler .